# Unable to view Xcode 4.2 help "index.html" is locked for editing

Tags: xcode, documentation

When viewing help documentation in Xcode 4.2 (iOS SDK 5) we get these error messages:

> "index.html" is locked for editing and you may not be able to save your changes. Do you want to unlock it?

> The file "index.html" could not be unlocked. The file is a remote resource. Try making a local copy.

How can we view online help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple but effective solution:

1. Open **Xcode** menu > **Preferences**...
2. Click **Downloads** category
3. Click **Documentation** tab
4. Select "iOS 5.0 Library"
5. Click **Check and Install Now**

This will download the documentation (about 360 MB) and solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to Xcode 4.2.1 will fix this problem